# Error: lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: expected '>'

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I have this XML data in a string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<class name="C" kind ="concrete">
    <inheritance>
        <from name="A" privacy="public" />
        <from name="B" privacy="public" />
    </inheritance>
    <private>
        <methods>
            <method name="C" type="C" scope="instance">
                <arguments></arguments>
        </methods>
    </private>
</class>
```

I want to find some elements using xpath. As far this is my code:

```
utf8_parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
root = etree.fromstring(string.encode('utf-8'), parser=utf8_parser)
somelist = root.findall(xpathString)
```

I got this error:

```
root = etree.fromstring(stringOutput.string.encode('utf-8'), parser=utf8_parser)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3032, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:68106)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1785, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102455)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1673, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:101284)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1074, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:96466)
  File "parser.pxi", line 582, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91275)
  File "parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:92461)
  File "parser.pxi", line 622, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91757)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: expected '>', line 11, column 11
```

I thought the problem could be with double quotes in the string. Is it possible? How should the proper code to find the elements using xpath look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double quotes delimiting attribute values are entirely fine, but the `method` element missing an end tag is not.  Here is your XML repaired to be well-formed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<class name="C" kind ="concrete">
    <inheritance>
        <from name="A" privacy="public" />
        <from name="B" privacy="public" />
    </inheritance>
    <private>
        <methods>
            <method name="C" type="C" scope="instance">
                <arguments></arguments>
            </method>
        </methods>
    </private>
</class>
```

Comment: Thanks, but another error occures. `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: methods line 4 and private, line 12, column 19`. Do I use lxml functions correctly?

Comment: The error indicates that the problem is in your XML, but I've double-checked that the XML in my answer is well-formed.  I suggest that you carefully double-check that you're using it exactly as provided.  Copy-and-paste would be safer than recreating it by hand.  If that doesn't work, create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I copied your repaired xml and used exactly that, so the problem shouldn't be in xml file and this is what I got: `File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 214, in prepare_predicate
    raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate")
SyntaxError: invalid predicate`

Comment: This is what I have in xpath string: `model/class[*/attributes/attribute/@name='var']/@name`

Comment: Now that's a new error.  Do you see how this is going?  You really have to post a ***[mcve]*** (preferably in a new question at this point) to avoid this sort of whack-a-mole mode.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36674120/lxml-findall-syntaxerror-invalid-predicate/36674153?noredirect=1#comment60940187_36674153

Answer (score 0):

XML validation using an online service gives you immediate help with validation errors, a web search for 'online xml validator' will yield many options.

```py
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: expected '>', line 11, column 11
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: methods line 4 and private, line 12, column 19
```

are both related to the tag `<method ...>` it is missing a closing tag:

```xml
        <methods>
            <method name="C" type="C" scope="instance">
                <arguments></arguments>
            </method>
        </methods>
```

> Here are two example online validators:
> [codebeautify xml validator](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator), simple explanation of each error.
> [w3c xml validation service](https://validator.w3.org/), more advanced, validating for xml and html.