# lxml findall SyntaxError: invalid predicate

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to find elements in xml using xpath. This is my code:

```
utf8_parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
root = etree.fromstring(someString.encode('utf-8'), parser=utf8_parser)

somelist = root.findall("model/class[*/attributes/attribute/@name='var']/@name")
```

xml in someString looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<model>    
<class name="B" kind="abstract">
    <inheritance>
        <from name="A" privacy="private" />
    </inheritance>
    <private>
        <methods>
            <method name="f" type="int" scope="instance">
                <from name="A" />
                <virtual pure="yes" />
                <arguments></arguments>
            </method>
        </methods>
    </private>
    <public>
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="var" type="int" scope="instance">
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </public>
</class>
</model>
```

When Im using `findall` I got this error:

```
raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate")
SyntaxError: invalid predicate
```

I tried to use `xpath` instead of `findall`. The script runs without errors but the `somelist` is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Switching from `xpath()` to `findall()` is not a solution. The latter only supports subset of XPath 1.0 expression (compatible to `xml.etree.ElementTree`'s [XPath support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax)), and your attempted expression happen to be part of the unsupported subset.

The actual problem is, that `root` variable already references `model` element, so you don't need to mention `"model"` again in your XPath :

```
somelist = root.xpath("class[*/attributes/attribute/@name='var']/@name")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. But isn't there a way to do it without removing model from xpath? The problem is that I don't know how the xml will look like and I don't know how the string in xpath will look like. Now I would have to manually check xml and xpath and find out wether the xpath is corrent according to given xml.

Comment: @T.Syk XPath should corresponds to the XML to be able to work correctly. There is no way to make arbitrary XPath works against arbitrary XML. If you receives the XML and the XPath from somebody else, then ask them to fix the XPath/XML.

Comment: @T.Syk If you only want to keep the "model" in the XPath somehow, you can start the XPath with `/` axis which references the document element : `/model/class[*/attributes/attribute/@name='var']/@name`