# XPath expression for getting this grandparent

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

I'm new to XPath and am working with an XML file which looks like this:

```
<doc>
    <component>
        <author> Bob </author>
    </component>
    
    <component>
        <sB>
            <component>
                <section ID='S1'>
                    <title>Some s1 title</title>
                </section>
            </component>
            <component>
                <section ID='S2'>
                    <title>Some s2 title</title>
                </section>
            </component>
        </sB>
    </component>
</doc>
```

I want to retrieve the component item above with section ID = S1, or alternatively the one that has a title element with text 'Some s1 title'. I cannot count on these things being in a particular order.

So far I've tried

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
res = tree.getroot().findall(".//*[title='Some s1 title']../../")
for i in res:
    ET.dump(i)
```

but that gets me both components, not just the one with the matching title.

I've also tried to search at the section ID level, like so:

```
res = tree.getroot().findall(".//*section[@ID='S1']/../")
for i in res:
    ET.dump(i)
```

but that doesn't get me the parent (the whole component) and instead just gets me the section.

Both of these *seem* like they might work from the simple example syntax I've seen online, but clearly in both cases I'm missing some understanding of what is actually happening. Could someone please clarify what is happening here and why I'm not getting what I would expect?

Comment: the xpath to get the component above section 'D1' is `//section[@ID='S1']/..`

Comment: Huh, that does work. Thanks Daniel. I didn't realize that last `/` would change the meaning.  And that `*` I put in front of section wasn't important either, apparently (but didn't hurt either). Can you elaborate on that versus the one with the `*` I put in front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are syntax errors with both of your XPaths:

1. `.//*[title='Some s1 title']../../` is missing an `/` after the predicate.  Then this one overshoots upward anyway.
2. `.//*section[@ID='S1']/../` cannot have a `*` before `section`.  This one would work otherwise.

But rather than repairing and working from there, you don't really need to select along the parent or ancestor axis — better to use a predicate higher in the hierarchy anyway...

---

This XPath,

```xml
//component[section/@ID='S1']
```

selects the `component` elements with `section` children with `id` attribute value equal to `'S1'`.

---

This XPath,

```xml
//component[section/title='Some s1 title']
```

selects the `component` elements with `section` children with `title` children with a string value equal to `'Some s1 title'`.

---

### Notes on Python XPath library quarks:

- ElementTree: [Noncompliant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax).  Avoid.
- lxml: Use `xpath()` rather than `findall()`.

**See also**

- [XPath SyntaxError: invalid predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65030434/290085)

Comment: Thanks, although unless I'm doing something stupid this doesn't work. When I try: ```res = tree.getroot().findall("//component[section/@ID='S1']")
for i in res:
    ET.dump(i)
``` 
I get:
`SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element`. Did I do something incorrect here?

Comment: The XPath's are correct, but if you want to use them in your Python / ElementTree code as is, try making them relative (`.//`) rather than absolute (`//`).

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too, using `res = tree.getroot().findall(".//component[section/@ID='S1']")
` but that gives me `SyntaxError: invalid predicate`. I've tested your XPaths with browser based tools and they work fine, but just can't figure out why this isn't working in Python.

Comment: Damn ElementTree.  As @DanielHaley mentions in another comment, [ElementTree is not fully compliant with the XPath standard](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax).   I advise you to switch to a better library [such as libxml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8692/290085).  I'm certainly not going to waste time dancing around faulty library support for a standard, and I suggest you do not either.

Comment: I tried lxml already and it's telling me the same thing, unfortunately, which makes me wonder if it's really the library. Though as I said, your Xpath does seem to work in browser testers so I dunno...

Comment: The XPaths are correct to the standard.  You're not the first to suffer these annoyances, but you should have better luck with lxml than with ElementTree. [This Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030511/290085) is similar and should help.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out I think. Apparently lxml's findall implementation is just as bad as ElementTree's (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36674153/1961582). If I instead search with lxml using the .xpath method it seems to work.

Comment: @gammapoint: Glad you got it working.  Updated answer to include mention of python library quarks for benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Craft your XPath expression to select `component` and then use the predicate (the conditions inside the square brackets) to determine which `components` you want.  Such as:

`component` containing `section` with `ID` = 'S1'

```
//component[./section[@ID='S1']]
```

or `component` containing `section/title` = 'Some s1 title'

```
//component[./section/title/text() = 'Some s1 title']
```

or component containing `section` with ID = 'S1' and that `section` has `title` = 'Some s1 title'

```
//component[./section[@ID='S1']/title/text() = 'Some s1 title']
```

and other variations thereof are possible.

Comment: You do not need the `./` before `section[..` . The expression `//component[section[@ID='S1']]
` is enough.

Comment: Also, [ElementTree has very limited support for XPath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax). Some/all of your examples may not work; even if they're valid and correct XPaths.